# "Refused to execute inline script" in ReactJS Chrome Extension even though there are no inline scripts

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, babeljs

I am familiar with Chrome's policy on inline scripts in Extensions. However, I don't think I have one in my files? All I have is very basic and I'm just attempting to place an input field onto the page.

main.js:

```
class Container extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="locationSearchBarContainer">
                <SearchBar />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <input className="searchBar" id="locationSearchBar" />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Container />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

main.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>New Tab</title>
    <script src="../scripts/plugins/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/plugins/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/plugins/babel.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="../scripts/main.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "",
  "description": "See what's happening around you and add events to your calendar",
  "version": "0.01",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides" : {
    "newtab": "html/main.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the actual full text of the error message?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that in this version of Babel you can't just prototype a site and include the library in a script tag, or it'll execute in-line. I don't have this problem anymore going through the Browserify route.

Comment: To clarify for others who may find find this question. The way 
babel-standalone operates is by using unsafe operations that are not permitted in browser extensions. This is why you have to precompile your files before including them to html (e.g. with browserify, webpack, parcel e.t.c)